# How would I know if a property is a generic collection

Tags: c#, generics, collections, propertyinfo

I need to know if  the type of a property in a class is a generic collection (List, ObservableCollection) using the PropertyInfo class.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo p in (o.GetType()).GetProperties())
{
    if(p is Collection<T> ????? )

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`GetGenericTypeDefinition` and `typeof(Collection<>)` will do the job:

```
if(p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && typeof(Collection<>).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
```

Comment: Shouldn't you test against something like `ICollection<T>` rather than `Collection<T>`? Many of the generic collections (eg, `List<T>`) don't inherit from `Collection<T>`.

Comment: `p.GetType()` will return a `Type` which describes `RuntimePropertyInfo` instead of the type of the property. Also `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` throws an exception for non-generic types.

Comment: Exactly, GetGenericTypeDefinition throws an exception for non-generic types.

Comment: i am using this `pi[index].PropertyType.IsGenericType && typeof(ICollection<>).IsAssignableFrom(pi[index].PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())` and worked perfectly for my case

Answer (score 33):

```
Type tColl = typeof(ICollection<>);
foreach (PropertyInfo p in (o.GetType()).GetProperties()) {
    Type t = p.PropertyType;
    if (t.IsGenericType && tColl.IsAssignableFrom(t.GetGenericTypeDefinition()) ||
        t.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == tColl)) {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name + " IS an ICollection<>");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name + " is NOT an ICollection<>");
    }
}
```

You need the tests `t.IsGenericType` and `x.IsGenericType`, otherwise `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` will throw an exception if the type is not generic.

If the property is declared as `ICollection<T>` then `tColl.IsAssignableFrom(t.GetGenericTypeDefinition())` will return `true`.

If the property is declared as a type which implements `ICollection<T>` then
`t.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == tColl)` will return `true`.

Note that `tColl.IsAssignableFrom(t.GetGenericTypeDefinition())` returns `false` for a `List<int>` for example.

---

I have tested all these combinations for `MyT o = new MyT();`

```
private interface IMyCollInterface1 : ICollection<int> { }
private interface IMyCollInterface2<T> : ICollection<T> { }
private class MyCollType1 : IMyCollInterface1 { ... }
private class MyCollType2 : IMyCollInterface2<int> { ... }
private class MyCollType3<T> : IMyCollInterface2<T> { ... }

private class MyT
{
    public ICollection<int> IntCollection { get; set; }
    public List<int> IntList { get; set; }
    public IMyCollInterface1 iColl1 { get; set; }
    public IMyCollInterface2<int> iColl2 { get; set; }
    public MyCollType1 Coll1 { get; set; }
    public MyCollType2 Coll2 { get; set; }
    public MyCollType3<int> Coll3 { get; set; }
    public string StringProp { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
IntCollection IS an ICollection<>
IntList IS an ICollection<>
iColl1 IS an ICollection<>
iColl2 IS an ICollection<>
Coll1 IS an ICollection<>
Coll2 IS an ICollection<>
Coll3 IS an ICollection<>
StringProp is NOT an ICollection<>
```